# For loop replaces all values with 41

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two csv files loaded into two separate dataframes which run through the same for loop. The 2018 df returns expected results, but the 2019 df does not for reasons unknown which is driving crazy. 
After the for loop, all values = 41.

I've confirmed that the 2019 data is not loaded into the DF with bad values.

```
import pandas as pd
#change display settings
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 25)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)

#load sites into dataframe
sites_2018 = pd.read_csv('sites2018_cleaned.csv', index_col='Site Name')
sites_2019 = pd.read_csv('sites2019_cleaned_copy.csv', index_col='Site Name')

#drop columns with all NaN values
sites_2018 = sites_2018.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
sites_2019 = sites_2019.dropna(axis=0, how='all')

#iterate through all cells using index and column headers to convert string values to numeric

##2018
column_headers2018 = list(sites_2018.columns.values)
for idx in sites_2018.index:
    for i in column_headers2018:
        value = sites_2018.at[idx,i]
        if value == '<10':
            value = 10
        if value == '>24196':
            value = 24196
        int (value)
        sites_2018.at[idx,i] = value

##2019
column_headers2019 = list(sites_2019.columns.values)
for idx in sites_2019.index:
    for i in column_headers2019:
        values = sites_2019.at[idx,i]
        if value == '<10':
            value = 10
        if value == '>24196':
            value = 24196
        int (value)
        sites_2019.at[idx,i] = value
```

Try print (sites_2019) before and after the for loop. You'll see the issue. 
Here is the source data: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k2oiyq066pb9vil/AABKSM19iItvJRn-oqQ6pwM3a?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

It appears there may have been a typo (`values` vs `value`). Since this assignment never occurs on your expected variable, you are comparing the value set from the previous for loop's last iteraton.

Inside your 2019 for loop:

`values = sites_2019.at[idx,i]`

Should be

`value = sites_2019.at[idx,i]`

Comment: It's probably a copying error. If this is in the real code, he'd get an error from referencing a variable before assigning it.

Comment: He creates and utilizes the initial reference to `value` in the first for loop but when performing the second for loop, his intention is to overwrite the same variable. Instead, he creates a NEW `values` variable but continues to use the already existing `value` variable which is never updated, thus leading to the repeated data.

Comment: For some reason I thought they were different functions, so the variables would be local.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Adrian!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please consider marking this answer as accepted if it solved your question. Cheers!